# How to install exfat-nofuse?

Tags: 13.10, kernel, fuse, exfat

Has anybody of you tried to install exfat-nofuse. 
I am not sure how to install it. Compile it as a module, or recompile my kernel?...

Also, do i have to recompile it after every kernel update? Will it be included in the kernel in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

Install Git and get the source code for Exfat-nofuse:

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/rxrz/exfat-nofuse.git
```

Install Exfat-nofuse:

```
cd exfat-nofuse
make
sudo make install
```

Load the Exfat-nofuse module to the kernel:

```
sudo modprobe exfat_fs
```

<sup>Source:[LinuxG](http://linuxg.net/native-support-for-exfat-filesystems-on-linux-will-be-added-soon/)</sup>

Comment: now i have to use modprobe exfat instead of exfat_fs