# Cannot manage to install exfat-nofuse

Tags: lubuntu, nas, modprobe, exfat

I'm using lubuntu, but still think it's very similar to ubuntu.
I need to install exfat-nofuse as my NAS has exfat format.

I followed these instructions on this post: https://askubuntu.com/a/400946/313828

Everything was fine until the last code:

```
sudo modprobe exfat_fs
```

All I get is this message: modprobe: FATAL: Module exfat_fs not found. Same result if I use exfat without '_fs'

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu 13.10?

Comment: The above command works on Lubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get install exfat-utils exfat-fuse
```

Comment: This will only work if the poster is using Ubuntu 14.04 or above, and is quite well answered by http://askubuntu.com/questions/451364/how-to-enable-exfat-in-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Sorry if I'm really late with this. I started only now to reuse lubuntu.
Thank you kyodake, your suggestion worked. Now I can access to exFat HDDs. 
I can't still manage to load it to the kernel (I get the same error). What exactly loading to the kernel should do? 

Back in September '14 I was using Lubuntu 14.04, now I did a clean install and I'm using Lubuntu 14.10.

Answer (score 1):

For exfat-nofuse module install using dkms:

```
sudo -i
cd /usr/src
git clone https://github.com/dorimanx/exfat-nofuse
mv exfat-nofuse exfat-nofuse-1.2.9
echo 'PACKAGE_NAME="exfat-nofuse"
PACKAGE_VERSION="1.2.9"
BUILT_MODULE_NAME[0]="exfat"
DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[0]="/kernel/fs/exfat"
AUTOINSTALL="yes"
MAKE[0]="CONFIG_EXFAT_FS=m make KDIR=$kernel_source_dir"
' > ./dkms.conf
dkms add exfat-nofuse/1.2.9
dkms build exfat-nofuse/1.2.9
dkms install exfat-nofuse/1.2.9
modprobe exfat && dmesg | tail -1
```

If successful output should be like `exFAT: Version 1.2.9`

Based on this post: http://www.lushnikov.net/2015/02/25/ubuntu-14-04-%D0%B8-exfat-nofuse/