# Building git package and trouble with CMake

Tags: 18.04, c, git-buildpackage

I'm trying to build finalhe and exfat-nofuse. It's my first time trying something of that sort. I'm using lUbuntu 18.04. I tried following info found on the finalhe GitHub page and these links: https://github.com/soarqin/finalhe/

[How to install exfat-nofuse?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/400865/how-to-install-exfat-nofuse)

https://www.reddit.com/r/vitahacks/comments/5nkgcu/theflow_finally_release_vitashell_update_with_usb/dccekoh/?context=3 (I can't seem to quote the specific comment appropriately, but it is the second one you see)

I get the following errors when trying to build finalhe with CMake and exfat-nofuse, respectively:

```
>>>>FOR FINALHE:<<<<

cmake ~/Downloads/finalhe-1.5
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:36 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindIconv.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Iconv", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Iconv" with any of
  the following names:

    IconvConfig.cmake
    iconv-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Iconv" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Iconv_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Iconv"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/myusername/Downloads/finalhe-1.5/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

>>>>AS FOR EXFAT-NOFUSE I GET THE FOLLOWING:<<<<

sudo make install
rm -f /lib/modules/4.15.0-33-generic/kernel/fs/exfat/exfat.ko
install -m644 -b -D exfat.ko /lib/modules/4.15.0-33-generic/kernel/fs/exfat/exfat.ko
depmod -aq
depmod: WARNING: Ignored deprecated option -q
sudo modprobe exfat_fs
modprobe: FATAL: Module exfat_fs not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-33-generic
```

I copied CMakeOutput.log onto https://hastebin.com/ejaralegub.sql

I thank you for your patience and comprehension in advance!

Comment: You should consult corresponding readme section [about dependencies](https://github.com/soarqin/finalhe/#prerequisites-for-build) and install corresponding packages.

Comment: That was the first thing I did, installed them all and got those errors. Tried reinstalling and still couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you don't have iconv installed. If that's the case, you can install it by installing libc6 or libc6-dev. Once installed, try building the package again.

Comment: Actually, those were already installed. I tried reinstalling them, but to no avail, got the same output for finalhe and exfat-nofuse.

Comment: So, it sounds like cmake just can't find it then. If you know where it's installed, you can explicitly tell cmake where to find it by setting the Iconv_DIR environment vartiable, i.e. export Iconv_DIR=/path/to/iconv

Answer (score 1):

Let's make it reproducible on clean 18.04 LTS.

## 1. FinalHE

To build finalhe we need to install the following.

```
sudo apt-get install git cmake build-essential libxml2-dev libusb-dev \
zlib1g-dev qtbase5-dev qttools5-dev libusb-1.0-0-dev qt5-qmake qt5-default
```

Then download source code (master branch, not v1.5 release!):

```
cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/soarqin/finalhe.git
cd finalhe
```

And build it with `qmake`:

```
qmake
make
sudo make install
```

And test it:

```
~/Downloads/finalhe/src/FinalHE
```

[image: FinalHE]

## 2. exFAT-noFUSE

Download and compile it:

```
cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/rxrz/exfat-nofuse.git
cd exfat-nofuse
make
sudo make install
```

Then load compiled module:

```
sudo modprobe exfat
```

---

Note: I have not used this software, just tried to compile it to help you.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time, the problem was that cmake couldn't find iconv to get things done. As the above user instructed, I specified the path and it worked like yours. Tried with qmake and also worked.